# Set Specific Record as default in Record Choice Set in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, multi-select

My flow starts by searching for a specific contact, then on the next screen there is a multi select picklist which lists all of the contacts at the account of the first contact. The thing is, I want to have the initial contact that was searched for selected as a default option, and then the user can select more contacts if they need to. But with the record choice set there isn't a way to select a specific record from within the set. Is there a good way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to first make sure the contact doesn't show up in the record choice set, then create a separate choice for your record and add it to the picklist and make it default.

The first contact you are search for name {!varContact}.

When defining the Record Choice Set, you can make it include Contacts where AccountId = {!varContact.AccountId} and Id Does Not Equal {!varContact.Id}. This makes it so that the original contact is not in the record choice set.

Then create a new choice and use {!varContact.Name} and {!varContact.Id} or whatever else you want as the label and value. Add this new choice to the list of choices in the multi select picklist and you will be able to make this one default.